# Load Runner - Where do I find the result collation in ubuntu load generator

Tags: performance, jmeter, loadrunner

I setup 2 load generators with for generating load from load runner controller which is a Windows controller. Now I am not able to find the result files (.eve) in my ubuntu machines. Anybody knows where LR keeps the collation files in unix/ubuntu Load generator.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this before. You have this information in the LG details screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Better question, why do you need to go to the LINUX load generator to manually grab the event files?